# ERR_REQUIRE_ESM when importing React Library bundled with rollup

Tags: reactjs, rollup

I'm already a couple of days trying to figure a way out of ERR_REQUIRE_ESM error.

I'm trying to create a React library on top of another React Library bundled with rollup.js

Thats my rollup config:

```
export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
        inlineDynamicImports: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
        inlineDynamicImports: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      json(),
      resolve({
        preferBuiltins: true,
        mainFields: ["browser", "module", "main"],
      }),
      commonjs(),

      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      // terser(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
];
```

and this is my package.js

```
...
...
"main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "ethers": ">=5.5.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "wagmi": "0.9.x"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js"
  },
...
...
```

*Update*

I also tried DTS, but the outcome was the same

Comment: Where are you trying to import it?

Comment: I’m importing in a React project